# How to convert Doc/Docx to PDF

Tags: pdf, docx, ghostscript, doc

How to convert a word document(.doc or .docx) to pdf file using ghostscript command line?
Tried using the commands "convert", "unoconv". But unsuccessful as in the server there is no LibreOffice or ImageMagic.

Answer (score 1):

Ghostscript can't accept Microsfot format (.doc or .docx) as an input. So there's no way you can take a Word doucment and directly convert it to PDF using Ghostscript.

For similar reasons you can't use ImageMagick's convert, because Word files are not image formats so IM can't read them.

You can print the document to a PostScript file, and then use that as the input for Ghostscript. On Windows by using RedMon you can set up a virtual printer to do all of that behind the scenes and 'print' directly to a PDF file. On Linux I expect you could do something clever with CUPS to get the same effect.

I believe that recent versions of Word cna export direct to PDF anyway, and I think both Libre Office and Open Office can export as PDF.